# How can I reindent/prettyify blocks of HTML code?

Tags: indentation, filetype-html, plugin-vim-jsbeautify

I've got a lot of HTML files, some of them with garbage indentation.

How can I select a block, and then prettify/reindent the HTML within, adding in newlines where appropriate? I can install any plugin necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Read `:h 'equalprg'`—you can set this to, e.g., `prettify` for html filetypes by placing a `setlocal` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`.

Then, use the `=` operator over a motion, text object, or Visual selection to prettyify that code.

Comment: Would this solve the problem with php+html indentation problems?

Comment: @klaus I have no idea